# What are the files and folders created automatically when creating new project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am currently learning java programming and just switched to JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA as I already use JetBrains PyCharm for Python programming and really like it.

Up to now I was using a simple text editor to write my java programs, but in IntelliJ they create a bunch of files and folders automatically when I create a new project, namely:

- A `.idea` folder containing some xml files
- An empty `src` folder
- A `NameOfMyProject.iml` file

I would like to know what they are, and if I can/should modify them. Also, should I write all my java classes and create subfolders/packages in the `src` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IntelliJ Platform (which is what JetBrains IDEs are based on) offers two project's formats

[image]

If you choose *Directory based* (note: seems the only choice for PyCharm)

there is an `.idea` folder per *project*.
there is an `.iml` file per *module* (which can be the project itself if there is only one).

The `.idea` folder keeps track of the workspace configuration

- code styles
- datasources
- dictionaries
- HTTP requests' outputs
- VSC settings
- compiler settings
- libraries
- UI state

The `.iml` file, instead

- language levels
- compilation output folders
- excluded folders
- source folders
- dependencies (manually inserted or via build system)

They're IDEA's project's structural components.
They're not necessary when working over VS Code, Eclipse, or other IDEs, however, they might be useful for *importing* purposes.

Comment: Btw., if a module in the project configuration window doesn't show the dependencies tab (Like so https://imgur.com/a/JZcdxoa), it's because the module is of the wrong type. Happened a few times to me. How to fix: Edit the .iml file and change `<module type="WEB_MODULE" version="4">` to  `<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">`